# Query DSL advance sorting with spring pageable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

) I have some problem with sorting and spring pageable when I use QueryDSL. I need quite advanced sorting, not just by the fields of the object stored in the database in the same table.

This is my model in approx:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Book {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @OneToMany
  private Set<Category> cats = new HashSet<>()

  } 

 @Getter
 @Setter
 @Entity
  public class Category{
    private long id;
    private Name name;
  }

 public enum Name{
  WINTER,
  SUN,
  SUMMER
 }
```

Now, this what I want to do is sort (desc and asc) Book (I have many Books) by Category id only if Category has name SUN. And i want to pass Qsort as Sort interface to PageRequest sping class.

I have no idea how I can achieve it. I try many way but none of these are even close to resolve this problem (for example some subquery with invoke any() on collection and use Qsort class). I affraid I made a mistake using Query DSL rather than Criteria Api. Can someone direct me? I will be very grateful.

Best Regards

Comment: I can't elaborate a full answer at the moment, but take a look at the [QuerydslBinderCustomizer](/) interface and [CaseBuilder](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.4/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/CaseBuilder.html).

Comment: @MarcTarin thank you very much. I'm going to research it :)

Comment: @MarcTarin  I see in this way I can filtering Book which has Category with certian name. In my case Book   has  always Category with name "WINTER" . And I want to search all my books (all books has exactly one category with name WINTER) and sort these  by Category id which has name "WINTER" . I think QuerydslBinderCustomizer and  CaseBuilder help me find Category with name "WINTER" but what about sort ?

Comment: Does the sorting need to be done programatically or can you simply use the sort parameter in a url?